# Thunderbird: keep Inbox clean

Tags: thunderbird

I tried to find a thunderbird plugin which can do this:

Display a button on the top of the message (while reading, not composing) "move message to folder '...'".

The plugin checks the "from" header of the mail and remembers (or searches) where the last mails of this sender were moved to. In about 95% of my cases the plugin could guess the correct folder. The algorithm is quite easy: move the mail to the folder, which was used the last time for this from-address.

This could help to keep the inbox clean.

I know a lot of people which have a huge inbox folder because they are to lazy (or busy) to move mails into subfolders.

I don't like the manual way: right click, move message to folder "...". And the archive feature of thunderbird does not help me. I want to keep mails separated.

Any idea how to keep the mail inbox clean by moving mails to subfolders in a way that is easy and fast?

**Update**

Filters don't solve my problem: I want to see all mails in my Inbox. After reading and handling the mail I want to move it to an other folder.

Comment: A good way is to use filters (with for example the "From" including this or that sent directly to this folder and marked as read)...

Comment: I updated the question: Filters don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try my addon [quickFilters](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quickfilters/). You switch it to learning mode, then move the email manually once. It will bring up a wizard so you can teach a filter to do this automatically from then on. It also integrates well with my other addon, QuickFolders. I also highly recommend using the "[Copy Sent to Current](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/copy-sent-to-current)" Addon to keep filtered conversations together and the [N] shortcut for jumping to the next unread mail.

As regards the Update, maybe you can define your filters not to run when "Checking mail" but only run manually; you still have the problem that they will be applied to all mails in the folder, so one would have to add a mechanism to avoid filtering unread emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can try addon called [archive-this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/archive-this/)

It works like this:

1. create a message filter (e.g. is from contact abc)
2. define the action (move to specific folder)
3. create preset keyboard shortcuts for triggering the action

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I already use the plugin "nostalgy" to move messages (I use "O" to move all online shopping stuff to a sub folder). I was looking for a "intelligent" solution. A plugin could guess the correct folder by looking at the header.

Comment: The last update for archive-this is from 2011. I guess it does not support current thunderbird versions.

Answer (score 0):

I get you. I use Gmail and have filters in Gmail that tag certain mails with specific tags. So the usual thing I do is jut click archive and it's out of my inbox.

Currently, using Thunderbird works fine.Those emails that are already tagged are present in other folder and clicking archive removes it from my the inbox.

In case that's not your case, you can just click & drag the mail to folder (I have "Unread" folders turned on). You can create a custom folder to archive all emails to it.